# Making a Movieclip Turn a Corner Convincingly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

How do you make a movieclip of a walking man turn a corner convincingly without it appearing to slide?

I have tried mixing if statements with counters for x,y and rotation but I can't get it right.

Here is my code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, zombieGo)
var rMod = 0;
var turned = false;
function zombieGo(e:Event):void
{
    var zPos = zombie_a.x;
    if(zPos > 100)
    {
        if(zombie_a.rotation != 180)
        {
            zombie_a.rotation++;
            zombie_a.x += 1 + rMod;
            if(rMod > -2 && turned == false)
            {
                rMod -= 0.02;
            } else {
                rMod = 0;
                turned = true;
            }

        }
        zombie_a.y++;
    } else {
        zombie_a.x++;
    }
}
```

I am using the gif animation seen here to test with:

[image]

Does anyone have a good function for turning movieclips using AS3 only? There must be a simpler way as I am trying to make a little game where a series of walker gifs follow a path that has many turns in it and I don't think having huge ladders of if statements is the correct way to go?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're seeing and what you want to see instead? If you rotate the zombie gif by making its point of registration (center) be where the head is, and rotating around that, does it accomplish what you're trying?

Comment: "Convincingly" is a bit vague, as Garry said you should elaborate on what you want to achieve. Although, I would think that this depends more on the animation than how the movement is programmed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think to do something along those lines is to split movement into Xmovement and Ymovement.

In you code you're incrementing x or y by one, so I'll assume 1 is the speed you want the zombie to move at.

So, I don't quite understand the logic for when a zombie should be turning, so I'm just going to write a function you can stick into your listener.

```
private const ZOMBIE_SPEED:Number = 1;

function zombieMove():void
{
    var xMod:int;
    var yMod:int;
    var yPercent:Number;

    yPercent = (zombie_a.rotation % 90) / 90;

    xMod = (zombie_a.rotation > 180 && zombie_a.rotation < 360) ? -1 : 1;
    yMod = (zombie_a.rotation > 90 && zombie_a.rotation < 270) ? -1 : 1;

    zombie_a.y += (ZOMBIE_SPEED * yPercent) * yMod; //
    zombie_a.x += (ZOMBIE_SPEED - yPercent) * xMod; //left over zombieSpeed
}
```

What this will do is, first figure out how much of the zombie's movement should be along the Y axis, then it figures out whether it should be moving left or right, then up or down. Then it applies the movement.

This isn't tested so there might be a bug in there somewhere.